# Why does flash video seem to skip less than HTML5 video when my computer's processor is busy?

Tags: windows, performance, flash, google-chrome, html5-video

Flash video seems stabler and less prone to playback hiccups when the computer's overloaded and busy. Why would this be? I would expect native browser video playback to be *more* stable and performant, if anything.

I'm in Google Chrome and windows, FWIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash has established itself for playing videos long before HTML, so if anything I'd expect the browser support to be less stable. After all, video in Flash had years to mature.

Also Chrome apparently does not use hardware-accelerated video decoding by default.

Comment: What does hardware-accelerated decoding refer to, exactly?

Comment: Your graphics hardware is usually capable of decoding H264 video on its own, thereby reducing load on the CPU (significantly, actually, since you also avoid copying the resulting image).

Answer (score -1):

This depends how the video is being streamed. The flash player you are using, might also be compressing the file, or streaming it differently then native html5 video.

Comment: I'm certain that bandwidth isn't the bottleneck.